# Scratch Org creation for Non-native clouds (e.g. Financial, Commerce, Marketing Cloud, Pardot,..)

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, pardot, steelbrick, demandware

We have developed managed packages for customers that extends Salesforce products that are not fully native like Sales Cloud. I mean products that you have to install in your org like

- Financial Service Cloud
- Marketing Cloud
- CPQ, Steelbrick, Demandware, Pardot

If I want to continue working on those managed packages using Salesforce DX the core question is

**"How to create and setup scratch orgs for those products?"**

Does Salesforce provide examples of scratch org definitions and setup scripts for those cases? Did anyone else do and share something for that.
The only thing I found was the [Falcon Demo Kit](https://github.com/sfdx-isv/fsc-demo-pack) which seems to do a lot of the plumbing for a Financial Cloud scratch org. But as it is a Plugin I cannot adjust it to my needs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Pardot, you might want to consider a plain scratch org and then install the Pardot Managed package by Package Version ID.  To get this, just use the sfdx command to list installed packages for the org, and you should get the Id.  While different, I did this for the LMA as I was developing code that extended it.

Now you won't actually get a Pardot instance, but if your code only relies on the changes made by the Pardot Managed Package, this might work?